# Bitnami lamp stack phpmyadmin password

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, lamp, bitnami

I installed Bitnami Lamp Stack in my Deepin Linux but it needed a password for login to PHPMyAdmin.
I tried to change the default password but it was not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Bitnami Engineer here,

The password you set during the installation process of the Bitnami LAMP solution is the one we use to configure the credentials of the different services. In this case, phpMyAdmin requires valid database credentials to access MySQL so you need to use "root" as user and the password you set during the installation process to access the database.

You can learn more about this here

https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/infrastructure/lamp/get-started/access-phpmyadmin/

Answer (score 0):

I found it is my **Linux user password**